# How to scale size and place image in center of Splash Screen of Android App

Tags: android, splash-screen

My exact purpose is to reduce the size (height and width) of the image slightly (as wrap_content size is too big) and to place it in centre of Splash Screen. But no matter what I do, it just doesn't get in center until I use wrap_content or match_parent. Here's the code I am using.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz.SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ss" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What would be the best way to go for it since setting a prefix size as I did would not let is adjust to bigger screens (tablets mostly).

Comment: what is the parent panel? Linear? Relative?

Comment: @d.moncada can you please tell how to check that. I am still a beginner in Android so I am quite confused. Although I have edited the question to provide all content on activity_splash_screen.xml file, maybe that can help.

Comment: your edit shows what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a constraintlayout for your parent panel, try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz.SplashScreen">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ss" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer nailed it perfectly. Can you please tell what exactly you did so I can also understand it better. :)

Comment: Since you are using a ConstraingLayout, I added constraints to all sides of the image (toLeftOf, to RightOf, toTopOf, and toBottomOf). This will force it to be in the center.

Answer (score 1):

**if you are using LinearLayout as parent then you need to set gravity as center to your parent LinearLayout to set children in center.As below**

```
     <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ss"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
 //  if you are using RelativeLayout then :
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ss"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer is also perfect, I just need to change the layout from Constraint to Linear or Relative.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your ImageView inside parent of linearLayout or relative layout.

then add ImageView with android:scaleType="center" and also dont forget to add centerInParent = true if using relative or android:gravity="center" for linearLayout.